# Redis Connection issue

Tags: redis, logstash, filebeat

I am trying to send my logs from filebeat into redis and then from redis into logstash and elasticsearch.
I am getting the error as
( Failed to RPUSH to redis list with ERR wrong number of arguments for 'rpush' command
2018-05-22T11:15:43.063+0530 ERROR pipeline/output.go:92
Failed to publish events: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'rpush' command).

What configuration is to be made in my filebeat.yml so that the output is redis
Also what configuartion is to be made in my logstash.yml when my input is redis.

Also I am getting error as Redis Connection problem when running logstash conf file

Please provide solution for this.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us the code that does the `rpush`?  Looks like pipeline/output.go on line 92 is a good place to start.  What is the error you get when you try to connect to redis?  What do you mean by "running a logstash conf file", can you show us how you "run" that?  A bit more information will hopefully allow us to help you

Comment: I am following the pipeline as "Filebeat-Redis-Logstash-Elasticserach-Kibana. I am trying to send my log file through this pipeline but i am unable to send the logs from filebeat to redis itself .I am getting error while running logstash as Redis connection problem